# Meaning of sentence with "vercingetorism"

Tags: meaning, is-it-a-word

This remark was made on an online forum.  Preliminary online search was of not much help.

> *(D)id you intend to deal with all this **vercingetorism**?*

This is certainly not a word from one of those obscure domains like psychology, medicine, etc., I hope.

What does the above expression mean?

Comment: What's the context? What is all this stuff that is being asked about?

Comment: If you are talking about [this comment](http://www.jeuxvideo.com/forums/1-60-6310388-6-0-1-0-les-tontons-flingueurs.htm#message_6310764), you probably should try the French.SE site.

Comment: Is there an Arverni SE site? You could check there.

Comment: Statement contrary to fact. This remark was not made on an online forum; a remark was made in French and this is only a machine translation.

Comment: @Kitḫ: [Asked](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1943/what-could-vercingetorisme-mean) and only partially answered so far.

Comment: @Mitch Oh Thank you, Mitch. You (unwittingly?) solved the whole mystery. Close-voters, FYI, it is NOT localized: please see the answer to the question Mitch has cited. And thank you Mustafa, I have found the answer elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably a word derived from [Vercingetorix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vercingetorix), the chieftain of the Gallic tribe of the Arverni. Your example could instead read:

> ... deal with all this formidable opposition.

Comment: Vercingetorism in that question seems to imply a certain (individual/group) behavior, though.

Comment: It sounds like "deal with all of this formidable opposition".

Comment: @Schroedingers Cat, yes, you are right because of -ism

Comment: @Mustafa - and then get so completely wiped out that historians don't even know where the battle and the massive fortifications were

Comment: When I read the question I was thinking, "Vercingetor-" sounds vaguely familiar, where does that come from? I wonder if the writer invented this word, or if this is a word actually in, well, I'm sure not common use, but have more than one or two people used it?